# How to create a schematic representation of a neural network?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

There are a lot of different examples for how to draw a neural network in LaTeX using tikz e.g. which show more details in terms of connections between nodes, however, I'd like to have a more schematic representation such as in [[2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.2738.pdf)] which looks like this:

[image]

I don't necessarily need a representation that looks *exactly* like this but something close to it would be neat.

What would be an easy way to do this?

Comment: This question is very broad. Could you please show us what you've achieved so far?

Comment: It's really hard to answer this type of "how shall could I design this?" question.  Can you make the question more specific?  Any of the regular drawing tools (tikz, xypic, metapost, asymptote, etc) could do this, but none of them is "easy" unless you have learned them.

Comment: @Thruston I have not learned any of them which is why I was hoping to get some help here. I'd prefer to do it with tikz since I am already using this package.

Comment: @TeXnician I haven't achieved anything so far because I would not know how to do this at all tbh.

Comment: What *can* you do? I would suggest using a `\pic` for the rectangle with circles and dots.

Comment: Take a look at the tutorials in the Ti*k*Z manual. You should be able to put together an example with at least the beginning of this: it is basically rectangles and straight lines. If you are already using Ti*k*Z, you can presumably draw at least that much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility with TikZ, probably be done more elegantly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  NNnode/.pic={
  \pgfmathsetmacro\RecH{2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\RecW{\RecH/10}
  \coordinate (-ll) at (-\RecW/2,-\RecH/2);
  \coordinate (-ur) at (\RecW/2,\RecH/2);
  \coordinate (-lr) at (-ll-|-ur);
  \coordinate (-ul) at (-ll|--ur);
  \path (-ul) -- (-ur) coordinate[midway] (-north);
  \path (-ll) -- (-lr) coordinate[midway] (-south);
  \path (-ll) -- (-ul) coordinate[midway] (-west);
  \path (-ur) -- (-lr) coordinate[midway] (-east);

  \begin{scope}[shift={(-\RecW/2,-\RecH/2)}]
  \draw (-ll) rectangle (-ur);
  \foreach \y in {0.05,0.5,0.75,0.85,0.95}
    \draw (0.5*\RecW,\RecH*\y) circle[radius=0.3*\RecW];
  \foreach \y in {0.275,0.625} {
    \fill (\RecW*0.4,\y*\RecH-0.1*\RecW) rectangle (0.6*\RecW,\y*\RecH-0.3*\RecW);
    \fill (\RecW*0.4,\y*\RecH+0.1*\RecW) rectangle (0.6*\RecW,\y*\RecH+0.3*\RecW);
    }
  \end{scope}
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={font=\scriptsize}]
\pic (I2) at (0,0) {NNnode};
\pic (I1) at (0,2.5) {NNnode};
\pic (IC) at (0,-2.5) {NNnode};

\pic [scale=0.7] (H1) at (2,0) {NNnode};

\pic (O1) at (4,0) {NNnode};

\foreach \i in {1,2,C}
{
   \draw (I\i-ur) -- (H1-ul);
   \draw (I\i-lr) -- (H1-ll);
   \node [left] (X\i) at (I\i-west) {$X_{\i k}$};
}
\draw (H1-ur) -- (O1-ul);
\draw (H1-lr) -- (O1-ll);

\node [right] at (H1-east) {$h_i$};
\node [right] at (O1-east) {$y_j$};
\node [below] at (O1-lr) {$V$-dim};

\node [above,anchor=south west,xshift=-5mm] at (O1-ur) {Output layer};
\node [above=5mm,anchor=south west,xshift=-5mm] at (H1-ur) {Hidden layer};
\node [right] at (I1-ur) {Input layer};

\path (H1-east) -- (O1-west) node[midway] {$\mathbf{W}'_{N\times V}$};

\node[right,yshift=-7mm] at (I1-east) {$\mathbf{W}_{V\times N}$};
\node[right] at (I2-east) {$\mathbf{W}_{V\times N}$};
\node[right,yshift=7mm] at (IC-east) {$\mathbf{W}_{V\times N}$};

\path (X2) -- (XC) node[midway,yshift=1mm] {$\vdots$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution with `pstricks` (compilable with `pdflatex` and the`--enable-write18` switch for MiKTeX, `-shell-escape` for TeX Live and MacTeX):

```
\documentclass[ x11names, border=3pt]{standalone}%{article}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{amsmath, pgffor}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\newcommand\layer[1]{{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}\setlength{\arraycolsep}{-0.65pt}\large%
\psDefBoxNodes{#1}{%
\fbox{$\begin{array}{c}\mathstrut \circ\\ \circ\\ \circ\\[0.3ex] : \\[0.5ex] \circ\\[0.3ex] : \\[0.5ex]\circ \end{array}$}}%
}}%
\newcommand\hiddenlayer[1]{{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.3}\setlength{\arraycolsep}{-0.65pt}\large%
\psDefBoxNodes{#1}{%
\fbox{$\begin{array}{c}\mathstrut\circ\\ \circ\\ : \\[0.25ex]\circ\\ : \\[0.25ex]\circ \end{array}$}}%
}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
\footnotesize
$ \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=3ex, colsep=1cm, mcol=l]%(-3,-3)(6,3)
x_{1k}\quad \layer{I1}\\%
x_{2k}\quad \layer{I2}\enspace \mathbf{W}_{V \times N} & \hiddenlayer{H}\enspace h_i & \mathbf{W}'_{V \times N}\quad\layer{O}\quad y_j\\
x_{Ck}\quad \layer{I3}%
%% Connections
\psset{linewidth=0.3pt}
\foreach \n in {1,2,3}{\ncline{I\n:tr}{H:tl}\ncline{I\n:br}{H:bl}}
\ncline{O:tl}{H:tr}\ncline{O:bl}{H:br}
%%% Labels
\psset{labelsep=1.5ex}
\nput{-10}{I1:tr}{\text{Input layer}}\nput{50}{I1:br}{\mathbf{W}_{V \times N}}
\nput{55}{H:tC}{\text{Hidden layer}}\nput{-70}{H:bC}{N\text{-dim}}
\nput[labelsep=0.25ex]{50}{O:tr}{\text{Output layer}}\nput{-70}{O:br}{V\!\text{-dim}}
\nput{-50}{I3:tr}{\mathbf{W}_{V \times N}}%
\nput{10}{I3:br}{C \times V\text{-dim}}
\end{psmatrix} $
\end{postscript}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you could approach the problem with [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).  I've wrapped it up in `luamplib`, so compile with `lualatex`.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
  picture wb_long, wb_short;

  wb_long = image(
      draw fullcircle scaled 4;
      draw fullcircle scaled 4 shifted 6 right ;
      draw fullcircle scaled 4 shifted 12 right ;
      label("$\dots$", 28 right);
      draw fullcircle scaled 4 shifted 44 right ;
      label("$\dots$", 60 right);
      draw fullcircle scaled 4 shifted 76 right ;
      draw bbox currentpicture withcolor 2/3 red;
  );
  wb_short = image(
      draw fullcircle scaled 4;
      draw fullcircle scaled 4 shifted 6 right ;
      label("$\dots$", 18 right);
      draw fullcircle scaled 4 shifted 30 right ;
      label("$\dots$", 42 right);
      draw fullcircle scaled 4 shifted 54 right ;
      draw bbox currentpicture withcolor 2/3 blue;
  );

  picture x[], h, o;
  x2 = wb_long shifted - center wb_long;
  x1 = x2 shifted 100 left;
  x3 = x2 shifted 120 right;
  h  = wb_short shifted - center wb_short shifted 60 down;
  o  = x2 shifted 120 down;

  drawoptions(withcolor 3/4 white);
  draw lrcorner x1 -- urcorner h; draw llcorner x1 -- ulcorner h;
  draw lrcorner x2 -- urcorner h; draw llcorner x2 -- ulcorner h;
  draw lrcorner x3 -- urcorner h; draw llcorner x3 -- ulcorner h;
  draw lrcorner h  -- urcorner o; draw llcorner h  -- ulcorner o;

  drawoptions();

  draw x1;  label("$x_{1k}$", center x1 shifted 12 up);
  draw x2;  label("$x_{2k}$", center x2 shifted 12 up);
  label("$\dots$", 60 right);
  draw x3;  label("$x_{Ck}$", center x3 shifted 12 up);
  draw h;   label("$h_i$", center h shifted 12 down);
  draw o;   label("$y_i$", center o shifted 12 down);

  label.rt("Input layer", (-200,0));
  label.rt("Hidden layer", (-200,-60));
  label.rt("Output layer", (-200,-120));

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

I've turned the design round, partly because it's simpler to code, but mainly because I think it looks cleaner like this (but that's just my opinion).

[image]

Add more `label` commands for the remaining text.